# how to fit xml file for all screen size of android phone?

Tags: java, android, xml, screen

I have created an android application. my app is currently working fine. but when i install this app to other device like 3.7" display size phone, some of activity's text view, button etc will cut. i want to make this auto for every screen size.

can you please inform me that how can i do that easily without bugs?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.gurujibd.bornomala.alphabet">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SorBorno"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BenjonBorno"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ShongKha"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PoriChiti"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You could create alternative layouts that only used for certain screen densities. See ["Supporting different screen sizes"](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#alternative-layouts)

Comment: thanks a lot @MichaelDodd

Comment: I suggest you to use `ConstraintLayout`, by using it correctly you can create complex yet shallow layouts that look good on small and large screen.